How to fully integrate QSystemTrayIcon with MacOS Sonoma Menu Bar?
In Sonoma, the MacOS Menu Bar changes it's appearance automagically, depending on the Wallpaper, Accessibility Settings, and perhaps other events.
The MacOS Sonoma menu bar can be black, white, or semi-transparent with the wallpaper color showing through. The OS seems to then pick whether the menu bar icon is black or white, and the app can control if it's greyed out.

Developing in Pyside6 (python wrapped Qt), the QSystemTrayIcon allows implementation of an menu bar icon, menu, actions, etc. as traditionally done in Qt, using QAction for menu items and callbacks.
    import PySide6.QtWidgets as qtw
    import PySide6.QtCore as qtc
    import PySide6.QtGui as qtg
    
    # Create the tray
    self.tray = qtw.QSystemTrayIcon()
    self.tray.setIcon(self.icon)
    self.tray.setVisible(True)

    # Create the menu
    self.menu = qtw.QMenu()
    self.action = qtg.QAction("About My App...")
    self.menu.addAction(self.action)

    # Add a Quit option to the menu.
    self.quit = qtg.QAction("Quit")
    self.quit.triggered.connect(self.app.quit)
    self.menu.addAction(self.quit)

    # Add the menu to the tray
    self.tray.setContextMenu(self.menu)

When the OS decides (wallpaper changes, etc.), or the application decides, the MenuBar icon color can change. My simple implementation above doesn't comply with icon color changes, as shown below.

How can I properly handle menu bar icon color preferences and change events in my PySide6 application?
The PySide6.7 QSystemTrayIcon docs state that use is possible on MacOS, but there don't seem to be  QObject methods to handle icon color configuration by the OS, and color change events.
(The icon shown above is a Google Material Design Icon, which is Apache licensed. )
Edit:
Most of the answer is solved here by setting the mask flag on the icon itself, before assigning it to the QSystemTrayIcon().
# Create the icon
self.icon = qtg.QIcon("img/widgets_96.png")
self.icon.setIsMask(True)

One part of the question still remains: how to set the icon to grey from my app? (This is shown on the Stage Manager and Focus icons in the images above).

This question is similar to: Create monochromatic tray icon for OS X using QSystemTrayIcon. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See QIcon.isMask(): add self.icon.setIsMask(True) before setting the icon.

Thank you.  This answers most of my question. The menubar icon is actually tri-state: black, white, and grey.  Seems like apps control whether it's grey or not. How to do that? I think I can hack it to make my own grey, with no mask set, but perhaps there's a better way?

I don't know, I haven't been using macOS for years and I only developed there with Qt4 and a very old OS (it was still called OSX, probably Snow Leopard).

As musicamante points out, this has been mostly answered here.
For allowing the OS to make the icon black or white, the icon needs to have it's mask attribute set, by calling setIsMask():
    # Create the icon
    self.icon = qtg.QIcon("img/widgets_96.png")
    self.icon.setIsMask(True)

For setting the icon grey when The app is not enabled (like the Focus and Stage Manager icons above), I could simply set a grey icon, with no mask set, I guess - but that doesn't handle the transparent (blue colored image above) case.
Thanks to musicamante, in the comments, and Giacomo for the solution 8 YEARS AGO.

Please don't create an answer if it makes it a duplicate of an existing one, instead accept the duplicate proposal.

Thank you.  The duplicate is not a complete solution for me. See my recent edits.   When this problem is completely solved, this answer will be less than the ultimate solution.

Are you referring to the partially transparent icons? (you mentioned "Stage Manager and Focus" but remember that not all of use may know to what those names refer) Have you tried to simply create the icon with a partially transparent color? You can even do it with Qt: src = QPixmap('image.png') alpha = QPixmap(src.size()) alpha.fill(Qt.transparent) qp = QPainter(alpha) qp.setOpacity(.5) qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, src) qp.end() alphaIcon = QIcon(alpha) and then call setIcon() when necessary. Alternatively, use alpha.save('alpha.png') so that you only need it once.

Thanks. This might be the right answer.  I'll try it.
